# window.open() popup=1 does not open popup in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, popup, cross-browser, window.open

In my web application, I am using the following code to open a new window as a popup:

```
window.open(
        '/auth',
        'mypopup',
        'popup=1,width=500,height=500'
      );
```

This code works as expected in Firefox, opening a new window with the specified dimensions. However, in Google Chrome, the window consistently opens as a new tab, seemingly ignoring the 'popup=1' attribute.

I've tried to control the behavior by explicitly setting the popup attribute, but it doesn't seem to have the desired effect in Chrome. Is there a cross-browser solution or workaround to ensure that the window opens as a popup in both Firefox and Chrome? I appreciate any insights or suggestions to address this discrepancy in browser behavior. Thank you!

Comment: works for me in chrome. `Version 119.0.6045.199 (Official Build) (arm64)`

Comment: _"Is there a cross-browser solution"_ - no, there is not. My browser is explicitly configured to _always_ open new tabs only, and never any real "stand-alone" popups.

Comment: @CBroe How did you configure Chrome in that way? Is there an option to open it always in a pop-up? I only found Extensions that claim to do that.

Comment: Not using Chrome, but Vivaldi (which is Chromium-based though.) The point is, you won't be able to _rely_ on this working, if you are not in control of the environment (like, intranet with administrated clients, where users can't change any such settings on their own.)

Comment: Understood, thank you!